# Call javascript Function on url click

Tags: javascript

I have a question, I want to know if their is a way to do it:
For Example i have online website, when I send that link to a person , whenever he click it or it is copied and pasted in the box of browser, then a function is called. The Function must be written in Javascript. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple html page(where you want to redirect user) eg. index.html

url would be http://yourdomain/index.html

create your html document as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function yourFunction(){

// wrire yiur js code here
}
</script>
<body onload='yourFunction()'>


</body>
</html>
```